# Cpu struck at 0.4 GHz after touching temperature of 50- 60°C

Tags: laptop, cpu, power-management, windows-11

Processor : Intel i5 10210U
Device : mi Notebook 14

When my CPU reaches around 50-60°C, it throttles and reduces its maximum frequency to a constant 19%. After that, the processor's base speed does not increase, as it cools down to 40°C in a matter of seconds.
To reset the throttling, I need to shut down and then boot the laptop.

I tried using the Power option to increase the minimum CPU usage stage and installing different versions of Windows 11 (because I suspected a Windows bug), and also Updated all drivers but nothing seemed to work.
[image: At freshly new boot]

[image: After some time]

Comment: Have you looked for a firmware update from you manufacturer?

Comment: https://mobile.mi.com/in/service/support/laptop-drivers.html seems a likely place for drivers, and things like the chipset, Intel ME and "power optimisation" packages could help. Make sure you get the right drivers for your machine.

Comment: Is this new, meaning did it always happen with this computer? If not, what has changed? You might have a bad sensor somewhere, try [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/) to stop the throttling. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc Yes , This is new It started happening from yesterday. When I boot up my laptop, it works perfectly, but when I start using a high-resource app, such as opening a browser, the CPU speed drops to 0.4 GHz and remains constant until I reboot my laptop. I tried throttlestop, but its FIVR control is locked, possibly because the BIOS has disabled undervolting, but I also can't configure it because the BIOS appears to be locked as well.

Comment: What do you mean by the BIOS being locked?

Comment: @KaranSingh Throttlestop is not being suggested to adjust the clock speed, it is to uncheck BD PROCHOT and nothing more. Most modern systems cannot use underclocking/undervolting due to spectre and similar data leaks.

Comment: @Mokubai When I unchecked the BD PROCHOT, the CPU frequency did not drop. Furthermore, after running Matthew x8 Stress Test for 3 minutes, the CPU reaches 90°C and the fan doesn't seems to running.

Comment: @harrymc As the BIOS was disabled, but I was able to enable it .

Comment: Does ThrottleStop work now?

Comment: @KaranSingh if the fan is not running then that would appear to be the fault causing your problem. BD PROCHOT is a signal that allows your system firmware to signal the processor to throttle in the event that something is going wrong, usually a thermal sensor tripping, but a faulty fan would also be a situation that merits throttling. You should replace the fan.